# When does the Collapsed Ceiling deal damage?

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

In the *Pathfinder Adventure Card Game*, the `Collapsed Ceiling` barrier card says in part:

```
If you fail the check to defeat by 4 or more, you are 
dealt 1 Combat damage that may not be reduced.
```

The check to defeat is 8.  Does the ceiling do damage if my check total is less than 12 or if it's less than 4?

Please help!  My domestic tranquility is at stake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither. The ceiling does damage if your check total is 4 or less.

...
check total = 3: Failed by 5 (failed by 4 or more): Failed with damage
check total = 4: Failed by 4 (failed by 4 or more): Failed with damage
check total = 5: Failed by 3 (failed by less than 4): Failed without damage
check total = 6: Failed by 2 (failed by less than 4): Failed without damage
check total = 7: Failed by 1 (failed by less than 4): Failed without damage
check total = 8: Passed the check
check total = 9: Passed the check
check total = 10: Passed the check
check total = 11: Passed the check
check total = 12: Passed the check<sup>[1]</sup>
...

Guessing from the little I know of the card, you're trying to dig your way through a room with a collapsed ceiling.

- If you roll 8 or more, you succeeded.
- If you roll 5, 6 or 7, you didn't make it through yet.
- If you roll 4 or less, you didn't make it through yet, and you hurt yourself in the process (dropped a rock on your foot, stabbed yourself on a piece of rebar, pulled a muscle, etc).

---

1. If your total is 12, you didn't fail the check, by 4 or by any other amount.

Comment: Bingo. +1 for chart.

Comment: The Collapsed Ceiling barrier, if you fail the check, stays on top of the location check until you or another player who moves into the location can pass the check.

Comment: This is as I argued, but my spouse wouldn't believe me without another opinion.

Comment: @Argyle, It can't possibly be less than 12 for the reason given in the footnote. Love your avatar :D